Backspace/Esc/Return keys require me to use Ctrl modifier to get them work with vim when using iTerm2 and 'Screen Sharing' app
I got a Mac Mini and I'm using the screen-sharing app to log into it from my MacBook Pro. It works, except there is this one quirk under the following conditions:

Using iTerm2 terminal emulator
SSH into another machine
Using Vim (or Neovim)
Using Screen Sharing app (the problem doesn't happen otherwise)

When in Vim (and only when in Vim), the Esc, Delete, and Return keys don't respond. I have to hit Ctrl+Esc, Ctrl+Delete, Ctrl+Return before they register.
If I log in with the stock Terminal app, everything works normally, and I don't need to use the Ctrl key.
Adding to the weirdness is that if I log into a Docker container with iTerm and then attach to the same shell process with Terminal, the problem no longer happens in iTerm.
Does anyone know what's happening and how I can fix it?

I started randomly fiddling with the terminal settings in iterm and stumbled up upon the fix:


set the "Standard key reporting mode" to on (checked)
ensure everything below that setting is off (unchecked)

It appears you have to set these manually each time you open a file with vim. However, editing the profile and going to "Keys" -> "General" and then selecting "Report keys as CSI u" seems to fix the matter.
